# Magento2: How to fix Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bxSlider is not a function in Magento2

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.2

In my `main.js` file I have included code for slider

```
   $(".main-slider").bxSlider({
            //mode:'fade',
            controls:false,
            pager: 'true',
            auto:false,
            onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){ 
                var newBg = $slideElement.find("span.banner-bg  img").attr("src");
                $slideElement.css( 'background-image', 'url(' + newBg+ ')');
            },
            onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex){
                $(".main-slider li").each(function(){
                        var newBg = $(this).find("span.banner-bg  img").attr("src");
                        $(this).css( 'background-image', 'url(' + newBg+ ')');
                });

            }
        });
```

and I get this `error`. Can someone help to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to wrap your code in the requirejs and connect modules.
Your module will be located in the `NameSpace_Module/web/js/your_module.js(bxSlider)`

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','NameSpace_Module/web/js/your_module'], function($,bxSlider){ 
        $(".main-slider").bxSlider({
            //mode:'fade',
            controls:false,
            pager: 'true',
            auto:false,
            onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){ 
                var newBg = $slideElement.find("span.banner-bg  img").attr("src");
                $slideElement.css( 'background-image', 'url(' + newBg+ ')');
            },
            onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex){
                $(".main-slider li").each(function(){
                        var newBg = $(this).find("span.banner-bg  img").attr("src");
                        $(this).css( 'background-image', 'url(' + newBg+ ')');
                });

            }
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check where bxSlider function is defined (lets assume in file jquery.bxslider.js), it looks like main.js script is loaded to the page before jquery.bxslider.js

Comment: These are the files which I am having 

<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>


and all these js files are included via require-config.js and
within main.js i have provided the function for bxslider.

Comment: @BridgitThomas have you found where bxSlider function is defined?

Comment: yes in main.js on the top of the file

Comment: if you could provide me your mail id I shall send my js file so that you can have look at it.